# Loader seems to be in an endless loop

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I've tried this with several different SWF files to make sure it wasn't something to do with the one I actually want to load

```
package 
{
import flash.automation.ActionGenerator;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Megan Morgan Games
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    private var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("CandyFactory.swf");
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, stillLoading);
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneLoading);

        myLoader.load(url);
    }

    private function stillLoading(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        trace("Still Loading");
    }

    private function doneLoading(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Done Loading");
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneLoading);
        addChild(e.currentTarget.content);
    }

}

}
```

The final product is a free to play online game that I wan't to be able to load the different "Scenes" individually, so I"m not embedding assets that aren't needed at that time.

When I run it, no matter what SWF I plug in, it traces the done loading repeatedly and nothing displays (I'm assuming because it can't keep up with a dozen different instances of the game at once).

Comment: Put a trace in the `init()` function to determine if that is being called multiple times.  Do you have any timeline code ?

Comment: I think it's best to master the basics before tackling something complicated like an online game.